# Getting date from the label onto the datepicker

Tags: ios, iphone, datepicker

I am working with the UIdatepicker. I am fetching the time from the datepicker and showing the date on the label. Once i select the date it is shown on the label and datepicker is hidden away. Now i want that when i call the picker it should show me the selection bar of the datepicker on the date of the label which i selected previously selected on the datepicker.Code i am using is shown below:-

```
-(void)datepickershown:(UILabel *)time animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select the Time" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"DONE" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
    pickdate = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:[actionsheet bounds]];
    pickdate.hidden = NO;
    //pickdate.date = [NSDate date];
    pickdate.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [pickdate addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDateInLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionsheet addSubview:pickdate];
    [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionsheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 500)];
    CGRect pickerRect = pickdate.bounds;
    pickerRect.origin.y = -90;
    pickdate.bounds = pickerRect;
}    

- (IBAction)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"I Am Changing the values");
    df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
}
```

Comment: plz elaborate this : 'Now i want that when i call the picker it should show me the selection bar of the datepicker on the date of the label which i selected previously selected on the datepicker.'

Comment: k i am adding the image with description plz have a look hope u will understand.

Comment: sry i cadd the image becoz of reputions..

Comment: actually what i want is, i am setting the time on the label from datepicker. Once i selected the time and date picker is closed, then i found that the time which i selected is wrong and now i again made a call for the pickker to appear. Now i want that the picker should show me the date which i selected earlier. But it is showing me the current date.

Answer (score 0):

As you want the datepicker to show the date you have already set on the label.

For this you need to use following method.

```
- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Pass the date whatever you have selected and is shown in the label.

Comment: are you providing current date?

Comment: actually i am fetching the time not the date ..... an dno i am not providing the currentdate to it.....

Comment: so from where it will show the date? you need somewhere to store and pass the date.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   [self.datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
   if([dateFormat dateFromString:yourDateLabel.text])
   {
      NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:yourDateLabel.text];
      [self.datePicker setDate:date];
   }
```

hope this will work